# Make the cell that matches with current day and time, a certain color

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to make it so the only cell that is pink, is the one that matches with the current day and time. However, right now I have it so the whole row of the time is highlighted pink. I also have it sorted by half hour, so if it's 3:11 PM the 3:00 PM row will be highlighted. Example of what I want it to be: if the time is 2:30 and its monday, I want the cell that matches up with monday and 2:30 to be pink.

```js
let today = new Date();
var d = today.getDay();
var weeks = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < weeks.length; i++) {
  var currentWeek = weeks[i].children;
  if (d < currentWeek.length) {
    currentWeek[d + 1].style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
  }
}
var n = today.getHours();
var x = today.getMinutes();
if (x <= 29) {
  x = "00";
}
if (x >= 30) {
  x = "30";
}
if (n >= 12) {
  z = "PM";
} else {
  z = "AM";
}
var todayyy = n + ":" + x + z;
var datte = document.getElementById(todayyy).parentNode.children;
for (var i = 0; i < datte.length; i++) {
  datte[i].style.backgroundColor = "pink";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>Calendar</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="tg">
    <tr>
      <th class="time">time</th>
      <th class="day" id="sunday">sun</th>
      <th class="day" id="monday">mon</th>
      <th class="day" id="tuesday">tue</th>
      <th class="day" id="wensday">wed</th>
      <th class="day" id="thursday">thu</th>
      <th class="day" id="friday">fri</th>
      <th class="day" id="saturday">sat</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="8:00AM">8:00 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="8:30AM">8:30 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="9:00AM">9:00 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="9:30AM">9:30 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="10:00AM">10:00 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="10:30AM">10:30 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="11:00AM">11:00 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="11:30AM">11:30 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="12:00PM">12:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="12:30PM">12:30 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="13:00PM">1:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="13:30PM">1:30 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="14:00PM">2:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="14:30PM">2:30 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="15:00PM">3:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="15:30PM">3:30 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="16:00PM">4:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="16:30PM">4:30 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="17:00PM">5:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="17:30PM">5:30 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="18:00PM">6:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="18:30PM">6:30 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="19:00PM">7:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="19:30PM">7:30 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="20:00PM">8:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your loop through the days of the week, set a `col` variable, then pass it in tp your `datte` array:

```
datte[col].style.backgroundColor = "pink";
```

```js
let today = new Date();
var d = today.getDay();
var weeks = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

let col;

for (var i = 0; i < weeks.length; i++) {
  var currentWeek = weeks[i].children;
  if (d < currentWeek.length) {
    currentWeek[d + 1].style.backgroundColor = "lightblue"
    col = d + 1
  }
}
var n = today.getHours();
var x = today.getMinutes();
if (x <= 29) {
  x = "00";
}
if (x >= 30) {
  x = "30";
}
if (n >= 12) {
  z = "PM";
} else {
  z = "AM";
}
var todayyy = n + ":" + x + z;
var datte = document.getElementById(todayyy).parentNode.children;
datte[col].style.backgroundColor = "pink";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>Calendar</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="tg">
    <tr>
      <th class="time">time</th>
      <th class="day" id="sunday">sun</th>
      <th class="day" id="monday">mon</th>
      <th class="day" id="tuesday">tue</th>
      <th class="day" id="wensday">wed</th>
      <th class="day" id="thursday">thu</th>
      <th class="day" id="friday">fri</th>
      <th class="day" id="saturday">sat</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="8:00AM">8:00 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="8:30AM">8:30 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="9:00AM">9:00 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="9:30AM">9:30 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="10:00AM">10:00 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="10:30AM">10:30 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="11:00AM">11:00 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="11:30AM">11:30 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="12:00PM">12:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="12:30PM">12:30 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="13:00PM">1:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="13:30PM">1:30 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="14:00PM">2:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="14:30PM">2:30 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="15:00PM">3:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="15:30PM">3:30 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="16:00PM">4:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="16:30PM">4:30 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="17:00PM">5:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="17:30PM">5:30 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="18:00PM">6:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="18:30PM">6:30 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="19:00PM">7:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="19:30PM">7:30 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="20:00PM">8:00 PM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```